# Unable to get subscription count using youtube data API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

So I just signed up my app for Youtube Data API V3.. I currently have the API key on hand.

Now.. I don't need to do any auth. I only want to access public information about different youtube channels.. such as their subscriber count, likes/dislikes per video, comments per video.. and that's about it.

Can someone point me to an example of hitting an endpoint to get sub count using a sample youtube account?

Thanks. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to combine the API key along with the API URL. On the website it shows what those get paramaters are for you to create the URL. What have you tried so far?